# Serial upvoting reversal fail

Tags: support

I got serially upvoted acouple of hours ago and the system (correctly) reversed this a few minutes ago...

*However* I also got a silver badge for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/601888/344926) but that was *not* reversed.  Should I mention this on Meta SE as well or is a bug tag here good enough for the powers that be to pick it up?

P.S. Removed bug tag after excellent answer...  **;-)**

Comment: Now you have reached 26 upvotes on that answer, so your silver badge it's deserved ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the badge and will keep it. It is by design.

See [Is the Critic badge awarded prematurely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-awarded-prematurely/2153#2153) for more information on this.